# Can azure/synapse pipelines be configured and deployed via scripting/config/properties files?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

For the `Hadoop` ecosystem we could configure and provision fully fault tolerant/failover-supporting clusters using `Ambari`. We would:

- start with the default `xml` properties files,
- convert hard-coded parameter values to replaceable parameters that would be updated by small scripts according to specific cluster needs
- test the scripts and further tweak
- check in to git and version successful results
- create deployment scripts for clusters with new capabilities by cloning the scripts, tweaking /adding new configurable parameters  as needed, and check in to separate paths

This approach made allowed tracking of changes needed for each type and/or version of cluster deployments and gave confident and repeatable results in predictable developer effort.

So far in Azure/Synapse all the work I've seen has been through working on GUI's. It can be a slow process and is not repeatable.  Is there at least some portion of this process that could be automated a la' `ambari`  (though likely with `json` instead of `xml`) ?